# What is the most used bi-polar output SMPS topology in gate driver isolation?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, gate-driving, negative-voltage, tl494

I have some questions concerning this schematic:

[image: updated sch for psu of gate drv]

What is the topology used here? I am guessing flyback without feedback circuitry.

Why is the [TPS40211](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps40211) utilized here? Is it to provide more current? Rather than using the 15 V of the input, this chip is used to provide more current for the [tl494](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf?ts=1673718737467&) which in turn will power the gate drivers to drive the IGBTs (which require +4 A). Am I right?

The transformer has two identical secondaries. Each one is used to drive the output of a gate driver, which requires a bi-bolar power supply. How can I use each secondary to provide both +15 V and -15 V?

There is a note in the gate driver transformer [datasheet](https://productfinder.pulseelectronics.com/api/open/part-attachments/datasheet/p0584nl): "These gate drive transformers are meant to operate between 50 and 300 kHz with a 12 V, 45% bipolar waveform". Does that mean it can't operate at 15 V?

The circuits are basically the same as the typical recommendation in the datasheet but I couldn't figure out the connection between the two ICs.

The circuit goes something like this:

[image]

Comment: We need some context here: what is this circuit from? What does it do, or supposed to do, or be a part of? Why does it have no designators (this makes it very hard to discuss)? Is `X?` missing a DC return path?

Comment: @TimWilliams This is a broken legacy gate driver board used to drive inverter IGBTs. I use this power supply to isolate the input and output sides of the gate driver and provide bi-polar rails (15V and -15V). I am currently trying to create a schematic for it.

Comment: @TimWilliams X? is a gate driver transformer and as far as I know, the primary side isn't connected to GND.

Comment: The two PNP BJTs driving the transformer primary look like they won't do the job; shouldn't there be some other components? Have you drawn it correctly? Please change your diagram to include reference designators and explain why the +15 volts needs boosting to 16.7 volts. Add all data sheet links and name the transistors on the schematic.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the C1/C2 net labels before. I guess they are cross-connected. PNPs would make more sense than N-MOS then, and the TL494 itself would be the DC return path. A tip, better to draw connections than to use net labels -- always go for clarity.

Comment: So what do you want to do with this, repair it? Make a new one? Is this power supply section a module on top of the drivers, or is there more? There are enough oddities in this circuit (as designed, that I don't think can be attributed to tracing errors) that I'd completely redesign it (but, I am a designer, so of course I would).

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah, I am planning to redesign it but first I need to review my schematic as there is always the possibility that I made an error during rev-eng. There are 3 tl494 each one providing power for 2 gate drivers which makes it a total of 6 gate drivers specifically for inverter applications. Why would PNPs make more sense than N-MOS? in the datasheet and in most TL494 schematics they always use MOSFETs! in the PCB these switching devices are SOT-23 packages with JCT8 SMD code so at first, I thought they might be transistors and then saw most schematic uses MOSFETs so I made them so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bespoke and inexperienced design.  The thought process seems something like:

**1. We need +15/-5V at the gates.**

(My assumption, since the gate drive section isn't shown.)

We can make -5 by regulating down (er, up) -15.  And we can make +/-15 by rectifying a 15V square wave.

Catch: the rectifiers drop a volt or so.  And the drive transistors, another one or two.

So let's boost the input up to 17V or so.

**2. We need something to make that square wave.**

Drop in a TL494, those make square waves right?

It appears to be hard-wired for fixed duty cycle, so there's no PWM going on here.  There's also no* current limiting, it's hard switching into the output filter caps (labeled as "100pF" but I'm guessing they're at least a few µF in actuality?).  It would be a forward converter, but there's no filter choke.  It would be a charge pump, but there's no series capacitor to pump charge through; instead it's transformer coupled.  It's the worst of both worlds...

*The TL494 can only sink 200mA or so, if you don't mind that its power dissipation goes way up when forced into current limiting.  Normally a series inductance (the transformer itself in a flyback converter, or the choke-input filter in a forward converter) limits dI/dt and therefore PWM can be varied to control output or peak current.  But with fixed PWM, this is not possible here.

The equivalent circuit looks something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxYJ8R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think you had Q3/Q4 correct the first time.

Q1 and Q2 are Darlington style internally, hence the higher voltage drop.  When Q1 is on, Q3 is also on, and T1 has positive voltage drop; when Q2 is on, Q4 is on and T1 has negative voltage drop.  It's a simple H-bridge arrangement.

Note that Q3/Q4 are not turned off very well: the C1/C2 voltage is only pulled up to V<sub>CE(sat)</sub> below VCC, which could be a significant drop under load current.  R3/R4 are fairly large so the reverse base current will be small; a B-E resistor would be welcome, to improve turn-off and reduce cross-conduction.  Perhaps the TL494 is set to low enough duty cycle that this isn't a problem; I didn't check.  (At I<sub>B(off)</sub> = 0, typical BJTs take about 10µs to turn off on their own.  Probably it's under 1µs here.)

TL494 is a full (if primitive) SMPS controller, so it's a bit of a waste here.  But it's cheap, and not much different in size from, say, a CD4047B, or a SN6501 plus cascode transistors.

**3. We have 15V input, but need 17.**

Maybe the input is variable as well, I don't know (could be a battery, unregulated (linear) supply, long wires, etc.).  The boost covers for a few possibilities.

TPS40211 is a poor choice, but that may itself be a mistake that was only discovered by doing.  I've made this mistake myself...  The problem is, its error amplifier output range overlaps the fault threshold, so it can't ever go into current limiting without faulting (stopping and restarting).  It can soft-start once, and that's it.

I'm guessing Q3 is misidentified and actually an N-MOSFET.  I suppose a BJT could be used, but R14 should be a different drive network, and even then, most gate drivers aren't rated for much DC output (which isn't to say they can't deliver it reliably, just that you don't know for sure).

UC3843 (and family) and LM3481 are better options for controllers; for regulators, CS5171 (and family), NCV3063 (and family); even MC34063 wouldn't be *terrible* here but it is rather slow so requires larger capacitors and inductor than others.  And myriad others I don't know offhand; probably lots in SOT-23-5 and up.  Also at these low power levels (assumption), some boost type LED/backlight regulators could be (ab)used if you really had to.

### What Should've Been Done

Just one transformer, flyback is fine, individual windings for each output.  This may need to be a custom part, but there are (somewhat roundabout) solutions using multiple single transformers / coupled inductors, wiring the primaries in parallel.  And if you don't find the right inductance and coupling factor, that's not a show stopper either: magnetizing inductance can be wired in parallel with the primary, allowing the use of generic pulse transformers.

Regulation can be based on the primary side, with a little care to avoid the overshoot due to leakage inductance.  Or one output can be chosen as priority, and a TL431 error amp and optoisolator connected there.  (Cross-regulation shouldn't be important as the gate drivers will all be active at the same time (assumption).)

If this is the usual +15/-5V gate drive that many IGBTs require, I would opt for a flat 20V output, and shunt regulate the "0V" with a zener.  The logic isolator and gate driver will be common-ground to the negative side, and the IGBT emitter ties to the "0V" zener node.  No DC flows through the gate normally, so very little bias is needed in the zener; a mA should be plenty.  Generous bypass caps shall be used, to ensure gate charge doesn't shift around the "0V" node.  Say, 10uF from +15 to 0, and 0 to -5.  Which can also serve as local bypass for the driver, no big deal.

So that basically cuts the circuit in half, or less.  Easy optimizations with a little thought; like I said, my guess is the original designer was inexperienced, perhaps rushed, and ended up accumulating a design rather than considering it holistically.

---

Some final tips:

If this is a lower power application (say, DC link up to 500V, load current up to 20A, give or take), bootstrap gate drivers may suffice, and then isolated supplies likely aren't required.  (If the output needs to be DC stable (0/100% duty cycle), isolated DC-DC for the high side is still a good idea.  Under 100V or so, a charge pump can be used.)  The bipolar gate drive will be harder to arrange, but at lower power levels, MOSFETs are more attractive and suitable with unipolar (e.g. +12/0V) gate voltage.

If you are [re]designing much more of this system than just the driver, include desat protection!  That is, a circuit that monitors V<sub>GE</sub> and V<sub>CE</sub> such that, if V<sub>CE</sub> rises significantly above V<sub>CE(sat)</sub> (say, a few volts) while V<sub>GE</sub> is "on", transmit a "panic" signal backwards across the isolation barrier (use a two-channel bidirectional logic isolator, or two optos).  At the controller, latch this signal into a fault and disable the outputs -- quickly, within 10µs.  The main downside to desat protection is nuisance tripping; it has to be delayed (slowed, filtered) enough that it doesn't trigger all the time (a little hard switching is usually necessary, i.e. turning on V<sub>GE</sub> while V<sub>CE</sub> is initially high), but not by so much that, in a short-circuit event, the transistor is destroyed (usually 5-20µs is the survival limit).  For a more integrated solution, consider ACPL-330J: pricey, but has everything you need, and you'll pay about as much for a more discrete solution.

(Desat protection can also be used with MOSFETs! You may need a higher voltage threshold, depending on R<sub>DS(on)</sub>, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The OP updated the question with complete schematic. So I edited my answer.

> What is the topology used here? I am guessing flyback without feedback circuitry.

True.

> Why is the TPS40211 utilized here? Is it to provide more current? Rather than using the 15 V of the input, this chip is used to provide more current for the gate drivers to drive the IGBTs (which require +4 A). Am I right?

Each secondary forms a flyback regulator, so the output will be one diode drop minus the secondary voltage. To guarantee 15V at the output the primary voltage should be adjusted to something above 15V. Apparently 16.7V is enough for the design. That's probably why a step-up regulator is used to generate 16.7V from 15V. If 15V was used directly the outputs would be somewhere around 14V.

> The transformer has two identical secondaries. Each one is used to drive the output of a gate driver, which requires a bi-bolar power supply. How can I use each secondary to provide both +15 V and -15 V?

Look at the polarity dots. When C1-leg is zero and C2-leg is positive the no-dot ends will be positive w.r.t. dot ends. Likewise, when C1-leg is positive and C2-leg is zero the dot ends will be positive w.r.t. no-dot ends. With rectifier diodes and capacitors you can get ±15V.

> There is a note in the gate driver transformer datasheet: "These gate drive transformers are meant to operate between 50 and 300 kHz with a 12 V, 45% bipolar waveform". Does that mean it can't operate at 15 V?

Doesn't. Volt-second product is important here. It's given as 95 V-usec (max) and the peak flux density shouldn't exceed 2100 Gauss (210 mT). In your case the switching frequency will be around 120 kHz (for given RT and CT) and duty cycle will be around 50% (There's going to be some dead-time but let's ignore it for worst case). So the pulse width will be ~4.1 us, and for 16.7V the V-sec product will be ~69 V-usec which is below the limit. And the peak flux density will be around 1400 Gauss which is below 2100 Gauss limit. So there's no problem.

Comment: @Rohit The VCC is only used for the TL494, the other parts are powered by the input 15V.

Comment: @YounesThabet see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would appreciate it if you could clarify these comments as well.
1. How did you identify it as a flyback, usually I identify it by the MOSFET and the isolated feedback.
2. I think the voltage doesn't need to be exactly 15V as the gate of IGBT can take up to 20V MAX, but the problem is the 4Amps that will be needed to charge the gate capacitor (so I thought that's why TPS40211 is used for).
TBH, I am still confused about the TPS40211!!